# C# I want to compare textbox value with all items in a combobox. I am getting an exception While clicking the button

Tags: c#, combobox

C# I want to compare textbox value with all items in a combobox. I am getting an exception While clicking the button.
Note: I have Combobox in another form.
Here Item is name of form and txtproducts is name of textbox . I want to put that textbox value of form1 into combobox of form2 named Item.

```
  `private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Item item = new Item();
            foreach (string obj in item.ComboBoxItems.Items)
            {
                if (txtProduct.Text != obj)
                {
                    item.ComboBoxItems.Items.Add(txtProduct.Text);
                }
            }
}`
```

Comment: What's the text in the exception message? My guess is that you refer to `ComboBox.items` as a string collection. but it is not...

Comment: Welcome. Thank you for taking the time to share your question. There is something missing. What is your goal & difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, dev env, data types & expected result, as well as to share more or less code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of screens, & user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: Indeed, what are the `Type` and `Message` of the `Exception` ? What are `Item` and `txtProducts` ? Is `ComboBoxItems` instantiated ? What there is in this combobox, items `Type` and `Count` ?

Comment: Disregarding the fact that you're working on a `new Item`, your logic seems flawed, as you should probably add `txtProduct.Text` to the combobox **only if it is not found** (right now you're adding it one time **for each** current item in the combobox that is not equal to it)

Comment: What is `Item`? Not a Form, right? If it is, you won't get anything anyway.

Comment: Here Item is form. This item form Contains combobox. txtprodcuts is Textbox from where i'm getting value and try to add it in combobox

Comment: When you do this: `Item item = new Item();`, you create a **new** instance of the `Item` Form (very bad name, change that ASAP), completely unrelated to the already existing instance. You need the **current instance** of the `Item` Form you have created and shown.

Answer (score -1):

<s>First, check that item.ComboBoxItems is not null, as you have just created the object item, so if it is not initilized in the constructor, probably the field ComboBoxItems  will be null.</s>

**------- EDIT ----------**

I just re-read your post and realized that Item is not just an object but an actual Form. If you create a new Item form every event, you are creating actualy a new UI object that never gets displayed, so it is pointless. Instead, you have to retrieve the reference to the instance of the Item Form that is really displayed and then do the combobox content check. I edit the code to show this. You should as well rename the Item form class to something less ambiguous as suggested in the comments (Like "Form_myItem", for example)

**-----------------------**

Then, check the type of ComboBoxItems.Items. It might not be a string collection but a collection of some other type, maybe 'object'. In that case, I would prefer to explicit the cast to string in the body of the "foreach".

Finally, as noted by Rafalon, you will be adding the same "product Text" for each element in your combobox. Maybe it is meant to be like that, but seems not really probable.

So, the code could be like this, based on the assuptions above (I'm adding a try/catch block that will help you debug your problem if it is not already solved).

```cs
   private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           try
           {
             Item item = myDisplayedFormItem; //myDisplayedFormItem is the instance of the form that is actually displayed
            bool ItemExists=false;
            string productText = txtProduct.Text;

             foreach (var obj in item.ComboBoxItems.Items)
             {
               if(obj==null)
                  continue;

                string ItemStringRepresentation = obj.ToString();
                if (productText  == ItemStringRepresentation)
                {
                    ItemExists=true;
                    break;                    
                }
             }

             if(!ItemExists)
                item.ComboBoxItems.Items.Add(productText);

            }
            catch(Exception excp)
            {
                //Manage you exception if needed
                //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); // Uncomment for debug purposes
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(excp.Message);
            }
    }
```

Make sure that you item object (or at least part of its information) persists beyond this method call, otherwise this code might be useless.

Comment: Now the Error has gone. but item is not adding in combobox

Comment: Make sure the cast is correct. I'm updating my answer to a more generic version, but still you should check the type of item.ComboBoxItems.Items and also if it is convertible to string the way you expect.

Comment: No Error. Even cast is correct. Everything seems to be flawless. I'm putting totally different item in textbox but item is not going to be add in combobox

Comment: It's already been warned in several answers that you are creating a new Item in the eventand if you don't do anything with this Item to make it persistent, the GC will deleted it when the scope of the event method "btnAdd_Click" is closed. So either you link the combobox of your item to a existing combobox in your GUI or make sure that the combobox that is being created in you Item is actually displayed. Force adding a dummy value to your combobox in the event and check it is displayed; if not, the issue may be related to your GUI architecture

Comment: Please check my edit on the answer. I just realized that Item is meant to be an actual existing form, so you must not instantiate a new Item every event call. Sorry, my mistake